# C++ including a file in multiple files

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to inherit a certain class into two subclasses in C++. I want the subclasses to run side by side, but they both inherit the superclass `entity.hpp`:

```
#include "../entity.hpp"
class Npc : public Entity
{}

#include "../entity.hpp"
class Human : public Entity
{}
```

Of course, when I do

`#include "Npc.hpp"`

`#include "Human.hpp"`

In the same file, I run into a problem because `entity.hpp` is included twice. How would I get around this?

**EDIT**: The .cpp files were a typo.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: @ahenderson, you should post your comment as an anwser.

Comment: Why are you trying to #include .cpp files ?

Comment: @PaulR that was a typo in the question.

Comment: @georgesl too late now, but I deleted my comment because I realize he was including implementation (cpp) files, which is a big NO!.

Comment: Make it a good habit to always use include guards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in `entity.hpp`:

```
#ifndef ENTITY_HPP_
#define ENTITY_HPP_

// code

#endif
```

Comment: Do I need the trailing underscore?

Comment: The trailing underscore is a naming scheme some people use to reduce the risk of name clashes with other `#define` values. Avoid leading underscores, because system include files use them.

Comment: @Ken you don't need it. The point is to avoid clashes, for which it is better to use longer and more specific defines, say `SOMEPROJECT_SOMENAMESPACE_ENTITY_H_`.

Answer (score 6):

Either use include guards in your headers, or the `#pragma once` directive (which is not as widely supported).

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code in the header file like this:

```
#ifndef ENTITY_HPP
#define ENTITY_HPP

<body of entity.hpp goes here>

#endif
```

Comment: So I would put these definitions in entity.hpp?

Comment: Yes. The second time entity.hpp gets included, ENTITY_HPP is already defined and the content is ignored. Just make sure that the include guards all have unique names.

Answer (score 0):

You should only include ".h" or ".hpp" files. If you use Visual Studio, add

```
#pragma once
```

To the top of your each header file. If you use other compiler, then

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_FILE_NAME
#define MY_HEADER_FILE_NAME

class Human : public Entity
{}

#endif
```

Comment: The first sentence is wrong, you can include `cpp` files as well.

Comment: It's not stupid if done right. Bulk builds speed up compilation time considerably in some cases.

Comment: Suggest you change *You can only include ".h" or ".hpp" files* to: *You should normally only include ".h" or ".hpp" files*.

Comment: Well first of all, *"if you use ..., add .... If you use ..., add ..."* - No, use that technique that works for all compilers in the first place (which is include guards). That being said, `#pragma once` is understood by other compilers as well, but it's still a platform-dependent extension for something achievable as easily with a single platform-independent technique. Your answer suggests that `#pragma once` is the way to go in VS. Include guards are the way to go on **each compiler**, and `#pragma once` an alternative on **many compilers**.

Comment: @micnyk It's neither stupid nor wrong per se. Sure it can be used poorly, or even abused, but so can just about everything else. But it can *also* be used right and sensibly. Case in point, I have a system where a lot of C code is dynamically generated by a program and must be compiled on the fly. Using a master .c file full of #include statements for the few hundred auto-generated .c files and a bit of extra glue makes a lot more sense that compiling all those indepedently and then linking them together.